# Jetpack Compose Render Problem NullPointer Exception in Design Screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have created an activity and when I run I see the results on my android device but I am unable to see the result using `@Preview @Composable` annotations in Design Screen and I always see a Render Problem. with Null Pointer Exception.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            createViews();
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun createViews(){
        ScrollableColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(color = Color(0xFFf2f2f2))

        )

        {
            Image(
                    bitmap = imageFromResource(res = resources,resId = R.drawable.logo_2),
                    modifier = Modifier
                            .size(100.dp, 200.dp)
                            .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop

            )

            Column(
                    Modifier.padding(20.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                        text = "Archi",
                        style = TextStyle(
                                color = Color(0xFFffd600),
                                fontSize = TextUnit.Companion.Sp(20)
                        )
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                Text(
                        text = "test",
                        style = TextStyle(
                                color = Color(0xFFf4511e),
                                fontSize = TextUnit.Companion.Sp(20)
                        )

                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                Text(
                        text = "xxx-xxxxxxx",
                        style = TextStyle(
                                color = Color(0xFF00e676),
                                fontSize = TextUnit.Companion.Sp(20)
                        )
                )
            }



        }
    }

    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun defaultPreview(){
        //Conmposable
        createViews();
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:97)
> at
> android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:134)
> at
> android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:128)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:592)
> at
> com.example.mvvmapp.MainActivity$createViews$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:43)
> at
> com.example.mvvmapp.MainActivity$createViews$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:155)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollKt.ScrollableColumn(Scroll.kt:528)
> at com.example.mvvmapp.MainActivity.createViews(MainActivity.kt:34)
> at
> com.example.mvvmapp.MainActivity.defaultPreview(MainActivity.kt:89)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewUtilsKt.invokeComposableMethod(PreviewUtils.kt:141)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewUtilsKt.invokeComposableViaReflection(PreviewUtils.kt:185)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$2$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:437)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$2$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$2.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:471)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$2.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:188)     at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:65)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:384)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:188)     at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:383)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:430)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.kt:293)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.kt:161)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:188)     at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AmbientsKt.ProvideCommonAmbients(Ambients.kt:276)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidAmbientsKt$ProvideAndroidAmbients$3.invoke(AndroidAmbients.kt:176)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidAmbientsKt$ProvideAndroidAmbients$3.invoke(AndroidAmbients.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:188)     at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidAmbientsKt.ProvideAndroidAmbients(AndroidAmbients.kt:168)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.kt:261)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:188)     at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:260)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:2906)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Composer.composeInitial(Composer.kt:2046)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:566)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:109)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:243)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.kt:548)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.kt:234)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.kt:285)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:241)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.kt:617)
> at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
> at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:361)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:696)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:852)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

**Dependencies**

```
def composeVersion  = "1.0.0-alpha10"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion"
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$composeVersion"
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$composeVersion"
    // Material Design
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion"
    // Material design icons
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$composeVersion"
    // Integration with observables
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:$composeVersion"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview works for me using 1.0.0-alpha11.

I had to add this:

```
val resources = AmbientContext.current.resources
```

and a content description to the Image, like this:

```
val resources = AmbientContext.current.resources
        Image(
            contentDescription = "",
            bitmap = imageFromResource(res = resources,resId = R.drawable.image),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp, 200.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop

        )
```

Are you sure you are using the canary version of Android Studio?

Comment: thanks for the reply...Yes I am using canary 2020.3.1 canary 4

Comment: thanks worked fine... don't know why resources doest work without proper context attachment. anyways thanks